# ocaml batteries unbound toploop error

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I am trying to install bap required for ropc https://github.com/pakt/ropc as per the instructions given in ropc/bap/INSTALL in Ubuntu 14.04 . I have run these commands successfully .

```
sudo apt-get install ocaml ocaml-native-compilers ocaml-findlib camlidl \
libocamlgraph-ocaml-dev libextlib-ocaml-dev binutils-dev automake \
libcamomile-ocaml-dev otags libpcre3-dev camlp4-extra bison flex
```

Now , when I make it inside the bap directory , I get the following Unbound module toploop error, which seems to be a compatibility issue between batteries and ocaml. How do I get around this ? Please see the image for further details

[Image uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZjAz.png)

I read that I should add *-I +compiler-libs* somewhere. But where exactly? I have no experience working with ocaml and I am just trying to build ropc successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile the pact/ropc project, and I can only confirm problems.

Although the ocaml configuration succeeds, the compile shows an undefined error:

```
Error: Some fatal warnings were triggered (2 occurrences)
../Makefile.shared:84: recipe for target 'nat.cmo' failed
make[2]: *** [nat.cmo] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/strobel/tmp/ropc/bap-0.4/bigint-3.12/otherlibs/num'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/strobel/tmp/ropc/bap-0.4/bigint-3.12'
Makefile:356: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
```

The bap component used in ROPC is available in [opam](http://opam.ocaml.org) but ROPC is not, and it shows signs of bitrot. There are 3 issues opened for the github project telling about compile problems.

I have a quite well provisioned ocaml setup, with packages directly from opam (very up to date versions), and my approach was to see if it would compile here.

### What to do?

Maybe uninstall your debian ocaml packages, start anew with opam. There is the possibility to install old ocaml versions, too, so maybe walk back in time to a 3.12 ocaml version. But getting the required packages in corresponding versions might not be so easy, opam is quite new. It will be an advanced ocaml debugging job IMO.

Comment: Is there anything specific I can do to get past the error I have mentioned, 'Unbound toploop' error ?

Comment: Thanks , I have no idea how challenging the task you mentioned is. Am i getting this error because the version of batteries included in ropc requires 3.12 ocaml? Since I am a newbie , I don't understand these dependencies quite well. What if I install BAP using opam now(latest version). Will ropc have a problem with that?

Comment: I am still not able to get it running. Few ques 1) You said bap component used in ROPC is available in opam , I have installed bap using ocaml 4.02.0 but was unable to install using ocaml 3.12.1 .  2) If I try to make ropc while using ocaml 3.12.1 as system's ocaml compiler , I get this error . `error: /bap-0.4/bigint-3.12/otherlibs/num/big_int.cmi is not a compiled interface`. And if I use ocaml 4.02 while making ropc it says `./bap-0.4/bigint-3.12/otherlibs/num/big_int.cmi
is not a compiled interface for this version of OCaml.
It seems to be for an older version of OCaml.`